# Show Bootstrap Modal Only Once using Boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a Bootstrap Modal and I want to have it show up only once when a button is clicked, but not if the button is clicked again.

I want to do this using a boolean that is initially true and when the button is clicked is set to false. I have actually found a solution just removing the Modal using .remove() after it is hidden the first time, but I want to know why a Boolean won't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncjbx/9/

```
var modalshow = true;
$("#button").click (function () {
    if (modalshow = true) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
        modalshow = false;
    }
})
```

Comment: `if (modalshow = true)` -> `if (modalshow == true)` (http://jsfiddle.net/ncjbx/10/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common syntax mistake. This:

```
if (modalshow = true) {
```

Should be this:

```
if (modalshow == true) {
```

As it is, you are setting `modalshow` back to `true` every time.

Comment: some might even say `modalshow === true`

Comment: Yes, good point, @NuclearGhost. Using `===` would be good too.

Comment: You know what, I considered that mistake and tried to fix it once, but did it the wrong way and gave up. Just goes to show, problems are much easier to fix once you know exactly what they are! Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (modalshow = true) {
```

to

```
if (modalshow == true) {
```